# How do I get p tag value in the select tag using jquery?

Tags: html, jquery

Here I have used jQuery. This code gives me output but I want output in a different way.

When I enter 5 digits in the input field, it gives me "one" in the select tag and "one, two, and four" in the p tag as my output.

Can I get like this if I click on "two" in the p tag, the value in the select tag should change into two? Can someone help me out?

```js
jQuery(document).keyup(function() {
  jQuery("#txtFirstNo").on("input", function() {
    jQuery("#selResult").val("");
    var arr = [];

    if (jQuery(this).val().match(/^(\d{5})$/, '')) {
      jQuery("#selResult").val("one");
    } else if (jQuery(this).val().match(/^(\d{5})$/, '')) {
      jQuery("#selResult").val("two");
    } else if (jQuery(this).val().match(/^(\d{5})$/, '')) {
      jQuery("#selResult").val("four");
    } else if (jQuery(this).val().match(/^(\d{7})$/, '')) {
      jQuery("#selResult").val("three");
    }

    // for p tag
    if (jQuery("#txtFirstNo").val().match(/^\d{5}$/, '')) {
      arr.push("one");
    }
    if (jQuery("#txtFirstNo").val().match(/^\d{5}$/, '')) {
      arr.push("two");
    }
    if (jQuery("#txtFirstNo").val().match(/^\d{5}$/, '')) {
      arr.push("four");
    }
    if (jQuery("#txtFirstNo").val().match(/^\d{7}$/, '')) {
      arr.push("three");
    }

    jQuery("#txtPrint").html(arr.join("<br/>"));
    arr = [];
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<br><b> Tracking Number :</b>

<input type="text" id="txtFirstNo" name="txtFirstNo" placeholder="Enter Number" /><br>
<b> Shipping Carriers :</b>

<select id="selResult">
  <option>Select Carriers</option>
  <option value="one">one</option>
  <option value="two">two</option>
  <option value="three">three</option>
  <option value="four">four</option>

</select>

<p id="txtPrint"></p>
```

Comment: Why does your code repeat the same condition multiple times? Is this a over-simplified version of some more complicated code you're using?

Comment: Also there is no need for two parameters in .match()

Comment: Why `value="three"` twice? Is that on purpose?

Comment: It has more regex conditions, so I have just made the code as simple as possible.

Comment: sorry, value three is a mistake.

Comment: Makes no sense to have that select box at all. - Or if you really want it, set some options to `hidden` to visuallyfilter-out carriers

Comment: So can you remake the code in the simple way with above mentioned question?

Comment: @KirthikaPillai sure. Added an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$("#txtPrint").html(arr.map(str => (`<span class="selP">${str}</span>`)).join(`<br/>`));
```

and then

```
$("#txtPrint").on("click",".selP",function() {
  $("#selResult").val(this.textContent);
})
```

```js
$(function() {
  $("#txtPrint").on("click", ".selP", function() {
    $("#selResult").val(this.textContent);
  })

  $(document).keyup(function() {
    $("#txtFirstNo").on("input", function() {
      $("#selResult").val("");
      var arr = [];

      if ($(this).val().match(/^(\d{5})$/)) {
        $("#selResult").val("one");
      } else if ($(this).val().match(/^(\d{5})$/)) {
        $("#selResult").val("two");
      } else if ($(this).val().match(/^(\d{5})$/)) {
        $("#selResult").val("four");
      } else if ($(this).val().match(/^(\d{7})$/)) {
        $("#selResult").val("three");
      }

      // for p tag
      if ($("#txtFirstNo").val().match(/^\d{5}$/)) {
        arr.push("one");
      }
      if ($("#txtFirstNo").val().match(/^\d{5}$/)) {
        arr.push("two");
      }
      if ($("#txtFirstNo").val().match(/^\d{5}$/)) {
        arr.push("four");
      }
      if ($("#txtFirstNo").val().match(/^\d{7}$/)) {
        arr.push("three");
      }
      $("#txtPrint").html(arr.map(str => (`<span class="selP">${str}</span>`)).join(`<br/>`));
      arr = [];
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<br><b> Tracking Number :</b>

<input type="text" id="txtFirstNo" name="txtFirstNo" placeholder="Enter Number" /><br>
<b> Shipping Carriers :</b>

<select id="selResult">
  <option>Select Carriers</option>
  <option value="one">one</option>
  <option value="two">two</option>
  <option value="three">three</option>
  <option value="four">four</option>

</select>

<p id="txtPrint"></p>
```

Comment: Can you show me with full code as I have mentioned above? Or in jsfiddle ?

Comment: See update. I did not touch the rest of the code other than to remove the weird ,"" in the match

Comment: It doesn't work when I add more values with same conditions

Comment: I have no idea what you mean. Please describe the issue in much more details

Comment: If I use one more condition for 5 digits

 if ( jQuery("#txtFirstNo").val().match(/^\d{5}$/, ''))
   {
    arr.push("five");
   }

then it does not show me the value from the p tag coming on the select tag

Comment: That is not part of your question. If you can create the array, then my code creates the link. So what are you asking?

Comment: My question is same but when I add more condition, it does not work

Comment: Your ORIGINAL was how to link the create array to change the select. I do not understand any of the logic you have in the creation of the array, so I have not attempted to answer any of that. Please write a new question with A LOT OF DETAILS on actual input and expected output. You have simplified the question too far to give a proper answer on your other question

Answer (score 0):

You are having basic issues with the conditional statements, it's working fine with the correct if statements:

```js
$(document).keyup(function() {
  jQuery = $;
  jQuery("#txtFirstNo").on("input", function() {
    jQuery("#selResult").val("");
    var arr = [];

    if (jQuery(this).val().match(/^(\d{5})$/, '')) {

      jQuery("#selResult").val("one");
    } else if (jQuery(this).val().match(/^(\d{6})$/, '')) {
      jQuery("#selResult").val("two");
    } else if (jQuery(this).val().match(/^(\d{7})$/, '')) {
      jQuery("#selResult").val("four");
    } else if (jQuery(this).val().match(/^(\d{8})$/, '')) {
      jQuery("#selResult").val("three");
    }

    // for p tag

    if (jQuery("#txtFirstNo").val().match(/^\d{5}$/, '')) {
      arr.push("one");
    }
    if (jQuery("#txtFirstNo").val().match(/^\d{6}$/, '')) {
      arr.push("two");
    }
    if (jQuery("#txtFirstNo").val().match(/^\d{7}$/, '')) {
      arr.push("four");
    }
    if (jQuery("#txtFirstNo").val().match(/^\d{8}$/, '')) {
      arr.push("three");
    }
    
    jQuery("#txtPrint").html(arr.join("<br/>"));
    arr = [];

  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<br><b> Tracking Number :</b>

<input type="text" id="txtFirstNo" name="txtFirstNo" placeholder="Enter Number" /><br>
<b> Shipping Carriers :</b>

<select id="selResult">
  <option>Select Carriers</option>
  <option value="one">one</option>
  <option value="two">two</option>
  <option value="three">three</option>
  <option value="four">four</option>

</select>
<br/>
Enter 55555 for one<br/> Enter 666666 for two<br/> Enter 7777777 for three<br/>

<p id="txtPrint"></p>
```

Comment: Lol by the time I completed writing the answer, you already got solution, Good luck!

Comment: Can you make the code without changing the conditions.

Comment: @KirthikaPillai yes but then you will have multiple same conditions assigning different values e.g `d{5}` is used twice by you, once setting value to `two` and then to `four` so you will only get `four` each time. You need to assign each value of `selResult` based on unique input from the number

Comment: d{5} means match any 5 number i.e 55555 or 66666 etc. If you only need to check based on length then you can use string.length instead of refex

Answer (score 0):

If you want to **filter your carriers** `<option>` depending on the **tracking number length** entered in the text input: make `disabled` and `hidden` the carriers which `data-len` attribute does not match the tracking number length:

```js
const $inp = $("#txtFirstNo");
const $sel = $("#selResult");

const toggleCarriers = (len) => {
  $sel.find("option").each((i, el) => {
    const isDisabled = el.dataset.len && +el.dataset.len !== len;
    el.disabled = isDisabled;
    el.hidden = isDisabled;
  });
};

toggleCarriers(0); // Init with 0 digits carriers

$inp.on("keyup", function() {
  $sel.prop("selectedIndex", 0);
  toggleCarriers(this.value.trim().length);
});
```

```html
<b>Tracking number:</b>
<input type="text" id="txtFirstNo" name="txtFirstNo" placeholder="Enter Number" /><br>
<b> Shipping Carriers :</b>
<select id="selResult">
  <option selected disabled>Select Carriers</option>
  <option data-len="5" value="one">one (5 digits)</option>
  <option data-len="5" value="two">two (5 digits)</option>
  <option data-len="7" value="three">three (7 digits)</option>
  <option data-len="5" value="four">four (5 digits)</option>
</select>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

No need to use unnecessary clickable `<p>` tags and other silly stuff. It's a form after all.